# Easiest technic for syncing files

Tags: iphone, database, synchronization

I am developing an iphone application and I don't know which would be the best approach to sync data between the application and a server.

I'd like to work with data in my application even if there is no internet connection, and sync the data when the device reconnects.

First I thought of using a local database, but I have no idea how to sync the records. At least, I can't imagine an easy way to do it.

- How could I sync a local database to a remote one?
- Should I think in using files (like json or xml) to store my data instead?
- How would I sync files?

Thanks.